# Why does the movie "Adaptation." have a period in its title?

Tags: title, adaptation-2002

I noticed on IMDB that [Adaptation.](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268126/?ref_=nv_sr_1) has a period at the end of its title. This can also be seen on its poster.

[image]

Usually titles and headlines don't use periods except for abbreviations, so why did they use one here?

Comment: Because it's an unusual title for an unusual movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Adaptation* is an adaptation of the nonfiction book *The Orchid Thief* and is a **"metafilm"**.

> Adaptation. is a 2002 American comedy-drama **metafilm** directed by Spike
>   Jonze and written by Charlie Kaufman. **The film is based on Susan
>   Orlean's non-fiction book The Orchid Thief, with numerous
>   self-referential events added.**
>
> **The self-loathing Charlie Kaufman is hired to write the screenplay
>   adaptation for Susan Orlean's The Orchid Thief.** Kaufman is going
>   through depression and is not happy that his twin brother, Donald, has
>   moved into his house and is taking advantage of him. Donald decides to
>   become a screenwriter like Charlie and attends one of Robert McKee's
>   famous seminars.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptation_(film)

So the title reflects several things relating to **a multifaceted approach** to the word, **adaptation**, because that is what the film is about:

1. A story about a **screenwriter adapting** someone else's *thought to be ludicrous* story (**Frame Story:** a story within a story, **Meta Frame Story:** based on a book, based on an article). So it in part relates to writers writing about other writers works or experiences in **various formats** and their experiences writing vs what really happened.
2. The questioning of what a good writer is, as the title is either incorrect or non conventional by having the period.
3. A **metaphorical** [full stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_stop), as the film is about **quests for finding meaning in life** and could also be seen as a **metaphor for writers block.** (Main character Charlie has this)
4. Adaptation Pun - A writer adapting another written work, based on a story about the **nature and survival** of Orchids, while examining human nature's adaptation to change, including the notion of **competition in natural selection.** (Note the title is also in green and features a fallen over plant).

The film is not only about the experience of the writers searching for meaning in life in order to write the most amazing thing (ie: taking credit), but also examines the differences between what gets written vs what the actual experience were and therefor, it scopes out to both the **natural reactions to the experiences** the characters have and/or the reality that a writer in many fields are subjugated to certain truths held by industry standards. In other words, **it showcases the struggle of subjugation itself and so the period is then proof of this notion
    and/or an ironic conceit in that surely there is more story to tell.**

Comment: Those bullet points are all well and good, but you might want work on how that actually connects to the period a little more. As of now they're pretty much just describing what the film is about rather than adressing the question asked. (Well, okay, except for the 3rd point maybe, but even that stands a little unexplained.)

Comment: @NapoleonWilson  I'm not sure how else to do that, because the period is about the nature of the film and the nature of the film is about multifaceted takes on "Adaptation".

Comment: Really, there has to be *some* way to explain that connection. You seem to very well have it in your head. You're really just listing things the film is about. Can't you relate that a tiny bit more to the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's a movie about screenplays. And good screenplays have good punctuation. Period is usually not used in titles or headlines because they should lead eyes to the article or poster.

But in this case it's not only a nod to the topic of the movie but also a FULL STOP. and what is a Full stop in the context of this movie? You need to figure it out.